# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError in Grails Compile?

Tags: java, grails, gradle, imap

I am upgrading a project from Grails 1.3.7 to 3.2.6.  I have classes which import such things as IMAPFolder and IMAPProtocol.  I believe that this requires me to include com.sun.mail:imap as a compile-time dependency.  I have this in my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'imap', version: '1.5.6'
```

However, when I add that and try to compile, I get a Java compilation error.

```
General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/ReadableMime

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/ReadableMime
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1089)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1067)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:525)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonServer.execute(CompilerDaemonServer.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/ReadableMime
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:545)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:676)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1218)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:176)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit$1.call(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1053)
    ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.ReadableMime
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 46 more
```

How do I get past this?  The imap library doesn't show any other compile dependencies on it, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`IMAPFolder` and `IMAPProtocol` are parts of JavaMail API.

You should add

```
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
```

instead of

```
compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'imap', version: '1.5.6'
```

Probably you need another version [see here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion.  I had a dependency for javax.mail in there, but a higher version.

I actually just solved this problem earlier this morning.  It turns out that I needed javax.mail version 1.4.3 (or thereabouts, but at least 1.4.3 worked) and the Sun imap 1.4.3 jar.  Gradle kept failing to pull the imap-1.4.3.jar from anywhere, so I downloaded it locally and it was finally happy.

So the suggestion of having javax.mail and the suggestion of a different version were both spot-on.

```
compile files('lib/imap-1.4.3.jar')
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.3'
```